# Rails using multiple databases - no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, octopus

I am trying to setup connection to another DB

```
class Something < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection {adapter:"postgresql",host:"localhost",port:5432,database:"dev_x",user:"user",password:"1234"}
end
```

But whenever I try to run a method on (e.g.: Something.all) it I receive error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth mentioning why I didn't use code properly. We are also using Octopus gem (gem for running multiple database). Native `establish_connection` method doesn't seem to work when Octopus is turned on :(.

For all of you out there - use `octopus_establish_connection` but beware: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/101

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Something` is an abstract class:

```
class Something < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true # <-------------------------
```

Abstract classes aren't mean to be instantiated directly, you're supposed to subclass them and instantiate the subclasses. The `abstract_class` property is, more or less, a way to subclass models without invoking STI (Single Table Inheritance).

Either use `Something` as a base class for models in the second database or remove the `self.abstract_class = true` to make it a "real" model class.

---

As far as where your `no implicit conversion of nil into String` error comes from, keep in mind that abstract model classes don't have table names and cannot be instantiated, from [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Shape < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
Polygon = Class.new(Shape)
Square = Class.new(Polygon)

Shape.table_name   # => nil
Polygon.table_name # => "polygons"
Square.table_name  # => "polygons"
Shape.create!      # => NotImplementedError: Shape is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
```